# React Native end game screen not show and crash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with my numbers game.

## Scenario

- Not showing up Game over screen after finishing the game
- App crash after the right number is found

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

import Header from './Components/Header';
import StartGameScreen from './screens/StartGameScreen';
import GameScreen from './screens/GameScreen';
import GameOverScreen from './screens/GameOverScreen';

export default function App() {
  const [ userNumber, setUserNumber ] = useState();
  const [ geussRounds, setGeussrounds ] = useState(0);

  const startGameHandler = (selectedNumber) => {
    setUserNumber(selectedNumber);
  };

  const gameOverHandler = numOfRounds => {
    setGeussrounds(numOfRounds);
    setGeussrounds(0);
  };

  let content = <StartGameScreen onStartGame={startGameHandler}/>;

  if (userNumber && geussRounds <= 0) {
    content = <GameScreen userChoice={userNumber} onGameOver={gameOverHandler}/>;
  } else if (geussRounds > 0){
    content = <GameOverScreen />;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Header title="Geuss a Number"/>
      {content}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

App.js

> Front end

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';

import NumberContainer from '../Components/NumberContainer';
import Card from '../Components/Card';

const generateRandomBetween = (min, max, exclude) => {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    const rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    if (rndNum === exclude){
        return generateRandomBetween(min, max, exclude);
    } else{
      return rndNum;
    }
};

const GameScreen = props => {
    const [ currentGeuss, setCurrentGeuss] = useState(generateRandomBetween(1,100, props.userChoice));
    const [rounds, setRounds] = useState(0);
    const currentLow = useRef(1);
    const currentHigh = useRef(100);

    const { userChoice, onGameOver } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
      if (currentGeuss === userChoice) {
            onGameOver(rounds);
      }
    }, [currentGeuss, userChoice, onGameOver]);

    const nextGeussHandler = direction => {
        if ((direction === 'lower' && currentGeuss < props.userChoice) || (direction === 'greater' && currentGeuss > props.userChoice)){
          Alert.alert('Don\'t LIE!!!!!', 'You know this is wrong...', [{ text: 'Sorry!', style: 'cancel'}]);
          return;
        }
        if (direction === 'lower'){
          currentHigh.current = currentGeuss;
        } else {
          currentLow.current = currentGeuss;
        }
        const nextNumber = generateRandomBetween(currentLow.current, currentHigh.current, currentGeuss);
        setCurrentGeuss(nextNumber);
        setRounds(curRounds => curRounds + 1);
    };

    return (
      <View style={styles.screen}>
          <Text>Opponent's Geuss</Text>
          <NumberContainer>{currentGeuss}</NumberContainer>
          <Card style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button title="LOWER" onPress={nextGeussHandler.bind(this, 'lower')}/>
            <Button title="CREATER" onPress={nextGeussHandler.bind(this, 'greater')}/>
          </Card>
      </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
      flex: 1,
      padding: 10,
      alignItems: 'center'
    },
    buttonContainer: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
      marginTop: 20,
      width: 300,
      maxWidth: '80%'
    },
});

export default GameScreen;
```

GameScreen.js I think the problem is in this script but I can't find it Please help...

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const GameOverScreen = props => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.screen}>
        <Text>The Game is Over!</Text>
      </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center'
  }
});

export default GameOverScreen;
```

GameOverScreen.js

[image]

Crash after finding the right number and try to get to the next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearly that you're getting an infinite loop. The error message has point out your issue: your `generateRandomBetween()` function. You should check your recursion and debug your input to find out what end-loop conditions have been forgotten.

Comment: setGeussRounds(0); Was placed wrong needed to be placed in startGameHandler!